# How to configure lxc 2.0 configueration file to use multiple overlayfs lowerlayer?

Tags: linux, filesystems, containers, overlay, lxc

I am using lxc 2.0 and using salt to invoke creation of container. I have multiple layers which I want to mount as overlayfs. I tried with lxc 1.0 using mount bind and it worked.

mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/firstlower:/secondlower,upperdir=/upper/root,workdir=/upper/workdir /merged

Since now lxc 2.0 supports multiple lower layers , I was wondering how to achieve it via lxc - conf file?

In following link I could find some description but its not enough for me to understand.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/lxc.container.conf.5.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution.

As link suggests we have to mention in conf file.

lxc.rootfs = overlayfs:layer1:layer2:layer3

But before this happens , we need to make changes in layers by mounting it using overlayfs (mount bind). This will create necessary configuration. You can extract this script which does changes from template.

Once changes are done start container directly with conf file and it should run.